# Using Socket.io in React Native and Hapi Server

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io, hapi.js

I'm trying to setup a simple socket io system for my React Native App (using Expo) to send messages back and forth from my Node Hapi server. Right now I have a print out on the Server to print when a connection is established however it is never printed. My Node server is hosted on a Amazon AMI instance using port 3030. Here are some code snippets. Any idea why the connection is not being made?

Server Socket IO Code:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server.listener);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Socket connection established.');
    socket.emit('connection', true);
});
```

Client Socket IO Code:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');

componentDidMount() {
    this.socket = io('http://{my_aws_instance_public_ip}:3030', {
        transports: ['websocket']
    });

    this.socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}
```

Comment: `io('http://{my_aws_instance_public_ip}:3030'` I assume that's not the actual code right?

Comment: right, {my_aws_instance_public_ip} is replaced with my public instance ip

Comment: does it work locally?

Comment: I haven't tried as I only run it on a device, not an emulator.

Comment: I was thinking maybe something to do with the server not being https.

Comment: well I would make sure the server works with or without the device. to eliminate it being a server problem. run your node server locally and make a quick html page to test the socket. create-react-app probably. the whole process would take 10 minutes

Comment: Pretty positive it works as its the same code I use in other projects using socket.io (not react native though)

Comment: Yeah I tested it locally and it works.

Comment: is this relevant? https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2045#issuecomment-244333643 can you share more code?

Comment: awesome that fixed it! not sure why that was causing an issue.